# pymongo, count query slower than mongo shell

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

everyone. I have a trouble at pymongo.

- pymongo 3.0.3
- MongoDB 2.6.10 (on localhost)

The following query run at the mongo shell, I got result in 3 seconds.

```
$ mongo mydb
> db.products.count({'categories': { '$elemMatch': {'code': /^11/}}})
891115
```

But, by python script via pymongo, I took 30 seconds to get the result.

```
$ python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Jun 26 2015, 04:26:33)

>>> import pymongo
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> cli = pymongo.MongoClient()
>>> coll = cli.mydb.products
>>> 
>>> coll.count({'categories': { '$elemMatch': {'code': re.compile(r'^11')}}})
891115
```

(Reference)

```
$ mongo mydb
> db.products.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "mydb.products"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "brand" : 1
                },
                "name" : "brand_1",
                "ns" : "mydb.products"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "categories.code" : 1
                },
                "name" : "categories.code_1",
                "ns" : "mydb.products"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "categories.code" : 1,
                        "brand" : 1
                },
                "name" : "categories.code_1_brand_1",
                "ns" : "mydb.products"
        }
]

> db.products.find({categories: {$elemMatch: {code: /^11/}}}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor categories.code_1",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 891115,
        "nscannedObjects" : 891115,
        "nscanned" : 891116,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 891216,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 891217,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 6962,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 2764,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "categories.code" : [
                        [
                                "11",
                                "12"
                        ],
                        [
                                /^11/,
                                /^11/
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "ip-10-4-0-124:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
```

Could anyone give me some advise, why it become slower when I run it with the python script?

Comment: Why do you use different versions of *pymongo* and *mongod*?

Comment: I tried pymongo version 2.6.3, 2.7.2 and 2.8.1, but did not improve.
`coll.find({'categories': { '$elemMatch': {'code': re.compile(r'^11')}}}).count()`

pymongo 3.0.3 does not support MongoDB 2.6? I read pymongo's changelog, but couldn't find that MongoDB 2.6 was deprecated.

Comment: I found that gave a `'code': '11'` instead of `'code': re.compile(r'^11')`, got the results in three seconds. But this is not yet resolved.

Comment: It solved. `'code': { '$regex' : '^11' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrong the query.
In prefix search, use 're' module of Python instead of  '$regex' of pymongo.

```
# wrong. MongoDB does not use index.
coll.count({'categories': { '$elemMatch': {'code': re.compile(r'^11')}}})

# correct. MongoDB use index.
coll.count({'categories': { '$elemMatch': {'code': { '$regex' : '^11' }}}})
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is strange. Did you run explain using Python's `re`? Because MongoDB uses index for regex whenever it starts with the `^`, so there might be no difference whether it is `$regex` or Python `re` object.

Comment: I checked and report.
'$regex version' is `'nscannedObjects': 891115`, 're version' is `'nscannedObjects': 8034295`.
Both queries used `'cursor': 'BtreeCursor categories.code_1'`, but indexBounds was different.
'$regex version' is `{ 'categories.code': [['11', '12'], [Regex('^11', 0), Regex('^11', 0)]] }`,
're version' is `{ 'categories.code': [['', {}], [Regex('^11', 32), Regex('^11', 32)]] }`.